# getting error while copy data from one table to another table, sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have two table named

```
state_master
location_master_state_master
```

Hi I want to copy data from one table to another but I am getting following error

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: INSERT INTO state_master(id, create_uid, code, create _date, name, write_uid, write_date) SELECT id, create_uid, code, create_date, name, write_uid, write_date FROM location_master_state_master; [ near "create": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
```

while executing below query

```
INSERT INTO state_master(id, create_uid, code, create _date, name, write_uid, write_date) SELECT id, create_uid, code, create_date, name, write_uid, write_date FROM location_master_state_master;
```

would anybody help me how to resolve this error?

Comment: You have a typo:  `create _date` vs `create_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space between `create` and `_date` which should be `create_date`:

```
INSERT INTO state_master(id, create_uid, code, create_date, name, write_uid, write_date) SELECT id, create_uid, code, create_date, name, write_uid, write_date FROM location_master_state_master;
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, Please accept it by checking the check mark.